# How to implement a TON timer like function in Groovy/Java

Tags: groovy, timer, plc

Basically, I need to compare two variables and start the timer when conditions met and set a variable to `true` if the condition sustains a certain amount of time. ( Similar to TON timer in PLC programming)
Example:
if `a > b` sustains for 5 seconds, then set `c = true`, otherwise set `c = false`

Comment: What have you tried ? Please update your question with your code and errors that you are getting.